# Create Java Pojo dynamically

Tags: java, xml, runtime, pojo

How can I create Java Pojo at runtime? ASM or BCEL is required for this?

I am reading a XML file and I want to generate Pojo according to this xml.

Comment: I think you are confusing POJO with [C++] POD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures

Comment: Do you need to create totally new classes or create instances (pojos) of a known class?

Comment: Yes, I need to create totally new Class

Comment: "... encoding business logic into regular java objects..." http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html

Comment: I will use http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of [libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries) available to generate classes in runtime. If you want to create a class and write it back to disk, BCEL and CGLIB is good. If you want most of them for runtime only, CGLIB is probably the best

Answer (score 0):

You might find that generating the code in memory is much easier to work with. (ASM is very good otherwise)  With generated code you just have to create the java you would need.

You can use tools like [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) or the Compiler API

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice open source library for reading xml to objects called [Xstream.](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) Use that and you don't need to worry about manually parsing the XML or manually creating objects.